# Problem installing canon software SCANGEAR MP

Tags: 14.04

When I try to install scangearmp-common I get : `E: Unable to locate package scangearmp-common`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scangearmp-common
```

How can i fix it ?

Comment: try with running `sudo apt-get update` again. then see if there is any line saying `failed to fetch.....`.

Comment: no there is not ..

Answer (score 1):

Reviving an old question, but I had the same issue today:

There are build errors in the `scangearmp` packages for 14.04. You can try installing the packages for your architecture (32bit/64bit) from the [ppa for 13.04/raring](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=raring) manually. This has worked for me (Canon MX920 over WLAN).

[scangearmp-common 32bit](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/scangearmp-common-32_2.10-33~raring1_amd64.deb)

[scangearmp-common 64bit](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk/+files/scangearmp-common-64_2.10-33~raring1_amd64.deb)

I guess you also have to install device specific package, in my case `scangearmp-mx920series`